# Proof of multi-index Taylor formula

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, reference-request

Assume that $f:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth.

Where can I find an elementary proof of the ***multi-index*** Taylor formula?

> $$f(x+h) = \sum_{|\alpha|\le k} \frac{1}{\alpha !} D^\alpha f(x)h^\alpha + O(|h|^{k+1}) \quad \text{ as } h \to 0$$
>   for each $k = 1,2,\dots$

Answer (score 8):

Take $g(t) = f(x+th)$. By the Taylor formula for $1$-variable we have:

$$g(t) = \sum_{j=0}^k \frac{1}{j!}g^{(j)}(0) t^j+ \frac{1}{k!}\int_0^1 (t-s)^{k}g^{(k+1)}(s)ds.$$

So
$$f(x+h) = g(1) = \sum_{j=0}^k \frac{1}{j!}g^{(j)}(0) + \frac{1}{k!}\int_0^1 (1-s)^{k}g^{(k+1)}(s)ds.$$

Notice that
$$g'(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n\partial_i f(x+th)h_i = h\nabla f(x+th)$$
where $h\nabla = \sum_{i=1}^{n} h_i\partial_i$ is a differential operator.

The second derivative will be
$$g''(t) = \frac{d}{dt} h\nabla f(x+th)= h\nabla \frac{d}{dt} f(x+th) = h\nabla \lbrace h\nabla f(x+th)\rbrace  = (h\nabla)^2 f(x+th).$$

By induction we have

$$g^{(j)}(t) = (h\nabla)^j f(x+th).$$

By the binomial formula we have:
$$(h\nabla)^j = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} h_i\partial_i\right)^j = \sum_{|\alpha| = j} \frac{j!}{\alpha!} h^\alpha \partial^\alpha.$$

Therefore $$g^{(j)}(t) =(h\nabla)^j f(x+th) =\sum_{|\alpha| = j} \frac{j!}{\alpha!} h^\alpha \partial^\alpha f(x+th).$$

Now just plug the formula above on the one dimensional Taylor and you obtain:
$$f(x+h) = \sum_{j=0}^k \frac{1}{j!}\sum_{|\alpha| = j} \frac{j!}{\alpha!} h^\alpha \partial^\alpha f(x)+$$  $$+\frac{1}{k!}\int_0^1 (1-s)^{k}\sum_{|\alpha| = k+1} \frac{(k+1)!}{\alpha!} h^\alpha \partial^\alpha f(x+th).$$

Simplifying the above expression you obtain

$$f(x+h) = \sum_{j=0}^k \sum_{|\alpha| = j}\frac{1}{\alpha!} h^\alpha \partial^\alpha f(x)+\sum_{|\alpha| = k+1}\frac{k+1}{\alpha!}\int_0^1 (1-s)^{k} h^\alpha \partial^\alpha f(x+sh)ds.$$

Now just observe that $\sum_{j=0}^k \sum_{|\alpha| = j} = \sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}$ and we obtain:

$$f(x+h) = \sum_{|\alpha| \leq k}\frac{1}{\alpha!} h^\alpha \partial^\alpha f(x)+\sum_{|\alpha| = k+1}\frac{k+1}{\alpha!}\int_0^1 (1-s)^{k} h^\alpha \partial^\alpha f(x+sh)ds.$$

That is essentially what you want. It is easy to see that the remainder is $O(|h|^{k+1})$ because $\partial^\alpha f(x+th)$ is continuous for all $|\alpha| = k+1$.

Comment: There is no proof in those notes.

Comment: I added some details, if something is not clear just let me know.

Comment: Just a detail, I am using $\partial$ where you use $D$. (It is kind of weird to use $D$ because we define $D = -i\partial$ on the PDE context.)

Comment: This helped me so much, thanks a million!

Comment: It was a while since I worked with BigO. Would you mind elaborating the last continuity argument? I get that the alpha-derivative of f should be bounded, but why in particular by $|h|^{k+1}$ eludes me.

Comment: @plebmatician I'm happy I was helpful and sorry for being late. Just now I saw your comment. On the remainder we have a sum of terms of the form $c_\alpha h^\alpha$, where $c_\alpha = \frac{k+1}{\alpha!}\int_0^1 (1-s)^{k} h^\alpha \partial^\alpha f(x+sh)ds$. The term $c_\alpha$ is bounded if you keep $h$ in a neighborhood of $0$ and $h^{\alpha}/|h|^{k+1} $ is bounded when $|\alpha| = k+1$. From that we have the remainder is $O(|h|^{k+1})$.